# Почему неправильно работает конечный автомат?

Tags: java, конечные-автоматы

Я попробовал сделать простой конечный автомат, который берёт строку и извлекает из него все слова в список. Я понятия не имею почему оно неправильно работает. Когда я ввожу несколько слов через пробел, то размер списка всё равно показывает 0. Помогите найти мою ошибку.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WordCounterMachine {
  private State state = State.OUTSIDE;
  List<String> words = new ArrayList();
  
  public void count(String line) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
      char c = line.charAt(i);
      switch (state) {
        case OUTSIDE:
          if (c != ' ' || c != '\n') state = State.INSIDE;
          break;
        case INSIDE:
          if (c != ' ' || c != '\n') sb.append(c);
          else {
            words.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
            state = State.OUTSIDE;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  static enum State {
    INSIDE, OUTSIDE
  }
}
```

```
import com.example.WordCounterMachine;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ln = scn.nextLine();
    WordCounterMachine wc = new WordCounterMachine();
    wc.count(ln);
    System.out.println(wc.words.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: `c != ' ' || c != '\n'` - всегда истинное условие. Любой символ не равен пробелу, кроме пробела, а пробел не равен переводу строки.

Comment: Пользуйтесь отладчиком чтобы посмотреть как программа работает. Это очень полезный в обучении инструмент.

Comment: Когда вы поправите условие, останется ещё одна ошибка: последнее слово не будет напечатано. После цикла нужно проверить не осталось ли в `sb` чего-нибудь.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я вторую ошибку понял, но первую понять не могу. Что нужно сделать?

Comment: `c != ' ' && c != '\n'`. А лучше `!Character.isSpace(c)`.

Comment: Ещё у всех слов будут срезаны первые символы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy хорошо понял.  Спасибо.

Comment: а вместо State не проще использовать boolean? или это для практики сделано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ошибка в условии `c != ' ' || c != '\n'` - оно всегда истинно. Должно быть `c != ' ' && c != '\n'`.
2. Первые буквы слов теряются. Как только вы переключаетесь в состояние `INSIDE` следует записать букву.
3. Последнее слово теряется. После конца цикла его надо добавить.
4. `new ArrayList()` - так делать не надо. `new ArrayList<String>()` или `new ArrayList<>()`.

Ваш код в одном файле, ошибки исправлены, добавлена печать слов:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class WordCounterMachine {
  private State state = State.OUTSIDE;
  List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  
  public void count(String line) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
      char c = line.charAt(i);
      switch (state) {
        case OUTSIDE:
          if (c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
            state = State.INSIDE;
            sb.append(c); 
          }
          break;
        case INSIDE:
          if (c != ' ' && c != '\n') sb.append(c);
          else {
            words.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
            state = State.OUTSIDE;
          }
          break;
      }
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        words.add(sb.toString());
    }
  }
  
  static enum State {
    INSIDE, OUTSIDE
  }
}

public class Temp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ln = scn.nextLine();
    WordCounterMachine wc = new WordCounterMachine();
    wc.count(ln);
    System.out.println(wc.words.size());
    for (String w : wc.words) {
      System.out.println(w);
    }
  }
}
```

**P.S.** Проверку на непробел лучше делать так `!Character.isSpace(c)`.

**P.P.S.** Гоняйте программу по шагам в отладчике. Многие вещи сразу становятся видны.